# Change date format to System's current format retrieved through database in Android

Tags: android, database, string, date

I have stored date in database,
first take the current date then convert it into String then store it into database,
it is working fine.

Then I want to retrieve the data and show it to ListView,
for that i did:

```
// get the string value of date

    String dateString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallHistoryDataBase.colDate));

// format according to system's current format

    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat =  android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
    textViewDateTime.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date(dateString)));
```

It is working fine,
like if I have stored date with **"dd/MM/yyyy"** format
and later I have changed the System's format to **"yyyy/MM/dd"**
in list it showing with **"yyyy/MM/dd"** format.

But some time it displays **2014/04/14** for date **2012/04/14**.
I have checked, at the time of storing and retrieving data to and from database it is fine.

I don't get any clue. There is no hard code, not even 14 number is there.

Any suggestion...
different solution is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getDate(final Context context, final long time) {
        long t = time;
        if (t < MIN_DATE) {
            t *= MILLIS;
        }
        final Calendar base = Calendar.getInstance();
        base.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        base.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        base.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        if (t < base.getTimeInMillis()) {
            SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            String formattedDate1 = df1.format(t);

            return formattedDate1;
            // return DateFormat.getDateFormat(context).format(t);
        } else {
            return DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context).format(t);
        }
    }
```

by using this method you can get date in dd-mm-yyyy formate.And pass data in database as millisecond time.
Hope its useful for you.

Comment: I don't want any rigid formate.
Like if I changed System's date formate to **dd/mm/yyyy** it list should display in this formate,including previously stored data.
Same thing should follow like later if I would change the date formate to **mm/dd/yyyy** the previously stored data should display in this manner.
This function has not solved my problem but from your suggestion I have passed data as millisecond and now it is working fine.
But still I'm in confusion that how 2014 may come.
I haven't change my retrieving method.

Comment: i am using above method and its working good,,,plz show your code.